# jQuery Templates not working in IE9 RC

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-templates

Just upgraded to the RC of IE9 and found that my web pages using jQuery Templates are not rendering the template content.

Pages work fine when I switch to IE8 Browser Mode in the Developer Tools (and Safari, FF, etc).

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Care to be more cryptic? What exactly doesn't work? Give us an error or a stack trace. A test case would be nice too. We can't guess what's wrong.

Comment: Seconding the request for a test case. I just threw together something quick in jsFiddle and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Hi to you both. Youre right, its not the jQuery Templates thats causing the problem. Rather, the browser is choking on some preceeding script. The Developer Tools debugger is showing the following: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName' 
jquery.min.js, line 16 character 59007
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName' 
jquery.min.js, line 16 character 59007
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'setDefaults': object is null or undefined 
qform.js, line 199 character 5

Comment: line 199 looks like this:     $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: '/Content/Img/calendar.png',
        buttonText: 'Calendar',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: 365
    });

Comment: If I remove the datepicker code, then the page renders fine. This problem only affects IE9.

Comment: Update: Reverting back to jQuery 1.4.4 (from 1.5.0) fixes the problem.

Comment: Update: This is a known bug - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was caused by a bug in jQuery 1.5 when running on an IE9.

The only way to get this working is to wait until the release of jQuery 1.5.1

See: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8052

Comment: Not the only way to get it working.  You can revert back to 1.4 and it works.

Comment: Hi Neil, Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a RC version of jQuery v1.5 - [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1rc1.js)
That should fix your problems with jQuery on IE9 RC. Full version of jQuery 1.5.1 is due to be released very soon.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code for usage of .text(), .contents() and replace those with .html().

IE has problems with those functions, only reliable way to grab content seems to be .html():
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1829-Script-Tags-jQuery-And-Html-Text-And-Contents-.htm

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed at latest version of jQuery. Upgrade to [1.5.1](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be fixed but is still an issue via asp.net!

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation