# Why is JQuery mobile not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

For some reason, JQuery mobile is not rendering in Internet Explorer 9 on my website - http://dev.eventhello.com/users/login. I tried it in compatibility mode and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas as to why it works in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there was a bug with JQuery version 1.5 so I updated. More details can be seen at [jQuery Templates not working in IE9 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004437/jquery-templates-not-working-in-ie9-rc)

Answer (score 0):

You have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` on line 33 of login page source. This results in javascript exception in IE which may stop the page from rendering.

Can you try adding empty string as initial source value:

```
$( "#EventCity" ).autocomplete({
                        source: "" });
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that error. I have fixed it; however, the issue persists.

Comment: now i get `Object doesn't support this property or method`. Pls enable script debugging in IE and check. Some javascript objects may not have same properties depending on the browser.