# What is jScrollPane-1.2.3.min.js and why's it not working?

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

I am maintaining a jQuery-enabled site which makes use of [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to have fancy looking scrollbars.

When testing in Internet Explorer 9 I was faced with the error "SCRIPT438 `getElementsByTagName` is not supported". This is a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004437/jquery-templates-not-working-in-ie9-rc) with jQuery 1.5 (which I was using) and probably unrelated to jScrollPane.

So, I upgraded jQuery to version 1.7.1. Fine, SCRIPT438 error is gone. However, jScrollPane now produces obscure JavaScript error `D is null` in `jScrollPane-1.2.3.min.js`. As I'm not the original developer of the site, I don't know where this file came from. It's nowhere to be found on [the official site](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

If I try [jquery.jscrollpane.min.js](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js) (from the jScrollPane site) instead, results are no good. The scroll contents show up when page is initializing but disappear when page is ready (no JavaScript errors). Isn't jScrollPane backwards-compatible?

Anybody understanding the different jScrollPane files and the cause of the errors I get?

Comment: Update: I upgraded both jQuery and jScrollPane to the latest version, but had to rewrite my DOM code to make things work. It was a painstaking effort which took hours. The problem seems to be jScrollPane is not backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the autoReinitialize option along with the latest version of jquery.jscrollpane.min.js:

```
$('.scrollpane').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true});
```

This will fix the issue where the scroll bars appear when the page is ready. I had this same problem a week ago, I now have a whole new problem which is how I stumbled on this question.

Comment: I've tried this a little bit more now, with different results, and setting `autoReinitialise: true`. When upgrading to jQuery 1.7.2 I get the error `P[0] is undefined` in `jScrollPane-1-2-3.min.js`. Go back to jQuery 1.4.2 and jScrollPane works again.

Comment: So I guess the original question of what `jScrollPane-1-2-3.min.js` is remains unanswered. The file appears here and there on the web, but there's no documentation. An educated guess would be it's an obsolete version, but if that's the case why is there no versioning number on the new jScrollPane implementation? And it's certainly not backwards compatible, which is something you'd expect it to be.

Comment: When using `jquery.jscrollpane.min.js`, the scroll container gets an invalid `margin-left` CSS attribute that causes it to disappear from view (this is the reason they disappear when page is ready). I can locate the scrollable items with Firebug. Seems to me that this is a bug in jScrollPane, or jScrollPane is not backward-compatible by design.

Comment: Based on JavaScript file naming conventions, my thinking is that it is a minified version of jScrollPane version 1.2.3. As far as the backwards compatibility issues it would be hard for me to answer on that as I've recently started using jScrollPane and have no experience with previous versions.

Comment: You're most likely right about that. Yesterday I got fed up with jScrollPane's backwards-incompatible behavior and tried [replacing it](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/). No alternative was satisfactory; either it was painfully slow or buggy. Most require new DOM items forcing me to rewrite lots of existing jQuery selectors. Don't want that. I would love to use CSS instead for styling scrollbars, but it's not supported in Gecko. So I guess I'm stuck with obsolete versions of jScrollPane and jQuery. :-(

Comment: Post your code into a Pastebin, including the jQuery and the jScrollPane and hopefully either I or someone else can help you figure out the issue. Are you using other JS libraries as well?

Comment: Thanks for the kind offering, but the amount of code is huge and not suitable for posting on the Internet. It's possible though that I can create a "minified" version that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I have now upgraded both jQuery and jScrollPane and things work as they should. However, I had to make a big effort and rewrite my DOM to make the new jScrollPane work. Seems it is not backward compatible.